# add tracks to "jump to file" queue winamp - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winamp

Is it possible from withing a vb.net application to add a list of songs into the jump to file box in winamp?  I've tried several ways but always came up short, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the options in winamp preferences